# How to find a specific cell and make it the ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA code that will open a specific worksheet in my workbook in Excel, and then find the cell in Column A that has the value "TOTAL". This then must be set as the ActiveCell, so that the rest of my macro can perform actions on the row containing this cell.

I want it so that when the user runs the macro, this cell is specifically chosen right off the bat. The position of this cell will change after the macro is run, so I need it to work no matter what cell this value is in. Everytime the macro runs, a new row is added above the row containing "TOTAL" and therefore the position of this cell is ever-changing.

So far I have come up with this, just from readin through forums. It still doesn't work, but I'm new to this language and I can't determine where the error is.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim C As Range
    Worksheets("Project Total").Select
    With Selection
        C = .Find("TOTAL", After:=Range("A2"), MatchCase:=True)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim cl As Range

    With Worksheets("Project Total").Cells
        Set cl = .Find("TOTAL", After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            cl.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, and the issue presented was a run-time error: "Select method of Range class failed."

Comment: It works fine for me. What does the error say and on which line is it thrown?

Comment: The issue appears on the line "c1.Select" and it is run-time error 1004. I think it must have to do with making c1 a Range?

Comment: I can't replicate the error. `cl` should be defined as a `range` object so not sure that is the source of the error.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was if you aren't already on the "Project Total" worksheet the macro can't access it. I wrote a line to switch to that worksheet every time and now your code works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub activateCellContainingTOTAL()

          'Go to the worksheet
          Worsheets("Project Total").Activate

          'Start going down column A to see if you find the total
           dim loopBool as Boolean
           loopBool = True
           Worksheets("Project Total").Range("A1").Activate
           Do While loopBool=True
                if Activecell.value = "TOTAL" then
                      loop = false
                else
                      activecell.offset(1, 0).Activate
                end if
           loop
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Getvaluesfromeachcolumns()

    Dim loopcounter As Integer
    Dim loopcounter1 As Integer
    Dim dumvalue As String
    Dim rrange As Range
    dumvalue = Activecell.value           'you can replace your cell reference or any value which you want to search. also you can use input method.'

    loopcounter1 = Range("A1:C1").Count
    
    For loopcounter = 1 To loopcounter1
    
        Cells(1, loopcounter).Select
    
        Range(ActiveCell.Address).Select  ' to know the active cell and address
        Set rrange = Range(ActiveCell.Address, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Find(dumvalue)
        
        rrange.Select

    Next loopcounter
End Sub
```